# swift valueForKeyPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, properties

I have function

```
func findObjectInArray(array: [AnyObject], field: String?, fieldValue: AnyObject, startFromTheBeginning: Bool, minIndexTemp: Int, maxIndexTemp: Int) -> AnyObject?
```

And there I have:

```
var minIndex = minIndexTemp
        var maxIndex = maxIndexTemp
        if (array.count == 0 || minIndex < 0 || maxIndex < 0) {
            return nil
        }
        if (minIndex > maxIndex) {
            let rem = minIndex;
            minIndex = maxIndex;
            maxIndex = rem;
        }
        if (maxIndex >= array.count) {
            maxIndex = array.count - 1;
        }
        let startIndex = startFromTheBeginning ? minIndex : maxIndex;
        let endIndex = startFromTheBeginning ? maxIndex : minIndex;

        for (var i = startIndex; (startFromTheBeginning ? i <= endIndex : i >= 0); (startFromTheBeginning ? i++ : i--)) {
            let object = array[i]
            var objectFieldValue: AnyObject? = nil
            if (field != nil) {
                print("test = ", (object as! SAd).adID)
                objectFieldValue = object.valueForKeyPath(field!)
            }
```

I logs before crash I see `test =  1` . So it means that `object` was converted to `SAd` and it has the field `adID`, but on the row `objectFieldValue = object.valueForKeyPath(field!)` application crashes with error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Project.SAd 0x12d731930> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key adID
```

Here is the class

```
class SAd: NSObject {
    var adID: Int!
    var bloggerID: Int!
    var createdOn: NSDate!
    var duration: Int!
    var fav: Int!
    var price: Double!
    var text: String!
    var countries: [String]!
    var categories: [String]!
    var deleted: Bool!
}
```

**Actually, you can test the same behavio in your code very simply:**

create class:

```
class STest: NSObject {
    var idTest: Int?
    var strTest: String?
}
```

and in your AppDelegate file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let testObj1 = STest()
    testObj1.idTest = 1
    testObj1.strTest = "test"
    let objValue = testObj1 .valueForKeyPath("idTest")

    return true
}
```

you will see the crash at line `let objValue = testObj1 .valueForKeyPath("idTest")`

**but if you replace this line with `let objValue = testObj1 .valueForKeyPath("strTest")` it will work. So the problem is in Int value**

Comment: Maybe the problem is that SAd is not inheriting from NSObject?

Comment: I updated the description, so you can see that SAd: NSObject

Comment: probably you have to cast `object` as well before calling `valueForKeyPath` : `(object as! SAd).valueForKeyPath(field!)`

Comment: I tried objectFieldValue = (object as! SAd).valueForKeyPath(field!) , but it doesn't help, I have the same error

Comment: I test this in playground and i probably dont get the same error, but it failed me for adID declared as :Int!, and passed when i set it to var adID:Int = 2 i know its not really a solution but its something :)

Comment: actually Yes, it works if you set the type as Int (not Int? or Int!) , but anyway the questions is why it doesn't work for type Int? or Int!  (but it works for String? and String! , for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use KVC with optional Swift numeric structure types, such as `Int`, `UInt`, `Float`, `Double`, and `Bool`. Simply put those types are not `AnyObject` compatible, and can't be bridged.

In your example, you could use:

```
var adID: NSNumber!
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `valueForKeyPath` with `Optionals`. Since you are declaring `idTest` as optional you are getting this crash. Try with below code and it should work!

```
class STest: NSObject {
    var idTest: Int = 0
    var strTest: String?
}

let testObj1 = STest()
testObj1.idTest = 1
testObj1.strTest = "test"
let objValue = testObj1.valueForKeyPath("idTest") as! Int
```

Comment: I understand, but it's really strange that I can't get the value of optional variable . I think that it must exist the right way

Comment: I do not have concrete answer to that. I guess that is how Apple has laid it out. Probably iOS is assuming that path can be `nil` and `valueForKeyPath` must take a non-nil value so this is a pre alert of a run time crash. A similar thread on this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759284/about-swift-execution-was-interrupted-reason-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-13

Comment: no, because String? is working well , the problem is only with Int?

Comment: valueForKeyPath has apparently been renamed since this post; per prompt by a playground error the last line of that now works as: `let objValue = testObj1.value(forKeyPath: "idTest") as! Int`