# update key values of NSManagedObjects safely

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, key-value-coding

I'm trying to pass key value pairs and have the attributes updated through a loop.

```
func update(storableClass : NSManagedObject.Type, id: ID, fields: [String : Any]) throws {

    // retreive manaagedObject
    for (key, value) in fields {
        manaagedObject.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Apparently the [`setValue(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue) will throw an exception if the key doesn't exist.

From what I've learned [you're not to catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494218/how-to-catch-nsunknownkeyexception-in-swift-2-2/37502496?r=SearchResults#37502496) an Objective-C exception in Swift.

Is there any safe way to update core data properties through a dictionary?

I know I can have a function like below:

```
func update(storableClass : ManagedObject.Type, id: ID, closure: (ManagedObject) -> ()) throws {}
```

and then call it as such:

```
update(storableClass: UserEntity.self, id: "123123", closure: { userEntity in
    userEntity.name = "new name" 
})
```

I like to have both options...and any other safe/swifty option...

Comment: @rmaddy Correct me if I'm wrong. I think objective-c is related because `NSManagedObject` are based off of `NSObject` and the `setValue` function is from objective-c...

Comment: Every UI class is written in Objective-C too. Your question is about Swift and how to deal with mistakenly calling `setValue`, in Swift, with an unknown key. The better question for you is why are you calling `setValue` with an unknown key? That's a programming error. You should try to catch the exception, you should avoid causing it.

Comment: Hmmm. You mean _That's a programming error_ vs. a **user** error or something out my control e.g. **server**?

Comment: the server isn't supposed to return a key that has no existence in your CD

Comment: Correct. There a difference between writing incorrect code and properly handling data.

Comment: @Sh_Khan right. But I have no control over what server sends...

Comment: then loop for the keys before inserting to verify it's in your model or not

Comment: @rmaddy How do I catch programming errors? I would then needs some extensive manual or automated testing. My current NSManabgedObject has 15 fields and some other relationships...

Comment: @Sh_Khan how do I verify if it's among the keys? I'm not aware of NSObject's `keys` property...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this exact problem. Here's what you do.

With Core Data, you can easily find out what property names are valid for the object. Get a reference to the managed object's entity, and then ask the entity for the properties. You'd use `managedObject.entity.propertiesByName`. The result is a dictionary where the keys are valid properties. The code would be something like

```
let properties = managedObject.entity.propertiesByName
for (key, value) in fields {
    if properties[key] != nil {
        managedObject.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    } else {
        print("Unknown key: \(key)")
    }
}
```

This is fine as long as `value` is the right type. If you start getting bogus data types in JSON, you have a more complex problem to solve.

For relationships, do the same thing with `managedObject.entity.relationshpsByName`.

Comment: FWIW there is also a type func called `entity()` which will have the same `propertiesByName` & `relationshpsByName`. Also a very good related read from Tom can be found [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/)

Comment: Hi Tom, happy holidays. When you get a chance can you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891194/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-coredatas-codegen-manual-none-cr). I don't think it would require any coding, hopefully you can validate my observations off top of your head :)