# What are the functional differences between Coredata's CodeGen 'manual/none + create NSManagedObject subclass' vs. 'category/extension'

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've read [Subclassing NSManagedObject with swift 3 and Xcode 8 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905456/subclassing-nsmanagedobject-with-swift-3-and-xcode-8-beta/37905573#37905573) and read [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/4/creating-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass-with-xcode) great tutorial. Still have questions on some points.

### The similarities are:

1. I can customize both classes however I like.
2. I can add new attributes or remove or rename attributes. ie for `category/extension` it will get updated upon a new build (in the derived data), and in case of `manual/none` it will leave the class file intact and update the extension in the file navigation ie I won't end up with a duplicate file. This is all handled by Xcode because they are marked with a preprocessor `@NSManaged`
3. Dumping something like `@NSManaged public var name: String?` straight into an existing `NSManagedObject` subclass is not allowed. I tried to do  `entity.name = "John"` but I got the following error:  `reason: '-[SomeEntity setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400009b120'`. I believe that's reasonable. I think without using the Core Data Model Editor the setter/getter accessor methods are not created.

## The differences are:

4. For `Category/Extension` you just need to create the class yourself and add any extra functions/properties you need.
5. For `Category/Extension` the attributes are created in derived data which is enough. Because you never need to see that file. Its existence is enough to get things working.

   And specifically in the context of making *changes* to your NSManaged properties:
6. Changing property type, e.g. `NSDate` to `Date` is allowed only for `Manual/None` . Example [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/4/creating-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass-with-xcode)
7. Changing optionality of a type, e.g. `String?` to `String` is allowed only for `Manual/None`. Example [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/4/creating-an-nsmanagedobject-subclass-with-xcode)
8. Changing a property access level, e.g. from `public` to `private` is allowed only for `Manual/None`. Example [here](https://medium.com/@kahseng.lee123/core-data-codegen-explained-462c30341041)
9. Having that said there is significant difference *if* I choose `Manual/None` codegen and but **don't** select 'create NSManagedObject subclass'. In that case I have start writing all the code myself (subclass from NSManagedObject and write NSManaged for every property)...or if I don't write all that code myself then I can still access/set fields using KVC which is awkward!

In a nutshell I'm just trying to figure out the full extent of capabilities that I can get from using `Manual/None`.

**Question:** Aside from the 9 *notes* which I need to know if I have validated correctly, an important *question* would be: how does me changing `NSDate` to `Date` or optional to non-optional not break the mappings between my NSManagedObject class and my object graph all while changing an `NSDate` property to `String` does break!! Does this have something to do with things that have guaranteed casting between Swift and Objective-C ie things that can be casted through `as` — without `?` or `!`?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647786/3985749) to a similar question might help.

Comment: Please see my edit. That answer is helpful, but it doesn't cover my edit.

Comment: I'm asking all this because in an existing project, Core data hasn't been used much but there are some existing classes. Now I want to just port them into core data. I just want to know beforehand what is the extent of changes that I can make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address each of your notes and considering the cases where codegen is set to `Manual/None` and `Category/Extension`:

1. Yes, in either case you can customise the classes however you like (within limits - for example, the class must be a subclass - directly or indirectly - of NSManagedObject).
2. Correct.  You can add, amend or delete attributes in the model editor.  In the `Category/Extension` case, the relevant changes will be made automatically.  In the `Manual/None` case, you can either manually update the Extension (or the class file) or you can redo the "create NSManagedObject subclass" which will update the Extension with the amended attribute details.  If you do not do this, Xcode will not recognise the new attribute details and will not provide code completion for them (nor will it successfully compile if you try to override code completion). But unlike what you think this has nothing to do with the properties being marked as `@NSManaged`.
3. Correct.  Adding an @NSManaged property to the class definition (or Extension) is enough to tell Xcode that the property exists (so you can reference them in code) but does not create the corresponding getter/setter.  So your code will crash.
4. Yes, for `Category/Extension` just create and tailor the class file as you require.
5. Yes, for `Category/Extension` the properties are declared in the automatically created Extension file in Derived Data.
6. Changing the property definition in any way - from Date to NSDate, or marking it private, or whatever - can only be done in the `Manual/None` case because the Extension file in Derived Data is overwritten with each new build so any changes are lost.
7. Ditto
8. Ditto
9. Correct.  You could write your app without ever creating separate NSManagedObject subclasses (automatically or manually), if you use KVC to access the properties.

As to your final point: you cannot arbitrarily change the type of the property definition: the type specified in the model editor must correspond to the type specified in the property definition.  You can switch between optional and non-optional versions of the same type, and you can switch between Date and NSDate etc, but switching from Date to String will not work.  I suspect you are correct that this is due to the bridging between Swift value type and the corresponding Objective-C reference type using `as`.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_foundation_types).

Comment: That link has nothing about optionals. Nonetheless non-optional to optional works: `var x : String = "x"; var y : String?; y = x as String?; print(y) // Optional("x")` While `as` doesn't work to convert optional to non-optional: `var k : String; var t : String? = "t"; k = t as! String` . Forced casting is required!

Comment: True, but the point is that the conversion can be achieved with a cast, forced or otherwise.  You can’t cast a Date as String.  The Swift language reference describes the use of is, as, as? and as! in the “Type casting operators” section of the Expressions chapter [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html).  It also refers to the bridging from Swift types to equivalent Foundation types.