# Handling Arithmetic Overflow UInt32 (CUnsignedInt)

Tags: swift, int, overflow

Is there a way using Swifts UInt32(CUnsignedInt) to handle arithmetic overflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these method here, I believe it's also the same methods across all `Int` of different sizes

`UInt32.addWithOverflow(x,y)
 UInt32.multiplyWithOverflow(x, y)
 UInt32.divideWithOverflow(x, y)
 UInt32.subtractWithOverflow(x, y)`

each of them returns a tuple of size 2 with the result and whether it overflowed or not.

Referenced from [How does one trap arithmetic overflow errors in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973899/how-does-one-trap-arithmetic-overflow-errors-in-swift)