# Catching an error from a non-throwing method

Tags: swift, int, double, try-catch, fatal-error

## Swift

Integers in Swift are ok. They cannot be infinite like Doubles, thought. They have a limit.
Surpassing that limit will cause a crash.

---

**Exhibit A**
`Int(10000000000000000000)`
`error: integer literal '10000000000000000000' overflows when stored into 'Int'`

---

**Exhibit B**
`Int(pow(Double(1000000000), Double(10)))`
`Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max`

---

I naively thought to myself, "Hey, this is a fatal error. Can I catch the error with a do, catch block?"
**Nope**

---

**Exhibit C**

```
do {
    Int(pow(Double(1000000000), Double(10)))
} catch {
    print("safety net")
}
print("good?")
```

`warning: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block`
`Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max`

---

Oh, yeah. That's right! I forgot to add *try*
**Nope**

---

**Exhibit D**

```
do {
    try Int(pow(Double(1000000000), Double(10)))
} catch {
    print("safety net")
}
print("good?")
```

`warning: no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression`
`warning: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block`
`Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max`

---

## What is going on?

Can anyone explain this to me? I would really like to be able to `catch` an error like this.
Thank you so much, this would be a huge help!

Comment: The Swift runtime considers integer overflows as being runtime errors, and are thus not catchable exceptions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973899/how-does-one-trap-arithmetic-overflow-errors-in-swift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `init(exactly:)` constructor, it will not throw an error but it will return nil if the value is to large

```
guard let value = Int(exactly: pow(Double(1000000000), Double(10))) else {
    //error handling
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Unfortunately, putting ```NaN``` values in ```init(exactly:)``` causes an overflow: ```func test() { guard let value = Int(exactly: 0.0 / -0.0) else { return } }``` here's the error: ```error: invalid conversion: 'NaN' overflows 'Int?'``` There's probably another init method so I can do some research on this. Good answer!